# How to add wrapper and bind to certain element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having 2 issues with my code:

1. I want to limit the effects of the script to the div `<div id="photo">`
2. How can I make a sub layer to the script so that all the elements in the page don`t change position when the animation is triggered.

This is my code hope you can help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>Untitled Document</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                .selected { border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color:#C00; margin:auto; z-index:2;}
                #cret {
                    position:relative;
                    z-index:3;
                    border-style:solid; border-width:5px; border-color:#000000;
                    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
                    margin:auto;
                    width:620px;
                    height:420px;
                }
                img {
                    position:static;
                    z-index:1;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"/></script>
        </head>

        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript"/>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('img').width('10%').height('10%');

                    $('img').on("click", function() {
                        $(this).wrap('<div id="cret"/>');
                        $(this).animate({width:'600px', height:'400px'}).addClass("selected");
                    });

                    $(document).on("click", function(){
                        $("img").unwrap();
                    });

                    $('img').click(function(){ return false; });    

                    $('#cret').click(function(){ return false; });

                    $(document).on("click", function(){
                        $('img').animate({width:'10%', height:'10%'}).removeClass("selected");
                    });

                    $('img').click(function(){ return false; });

                    $('#cret').click(function(){ return false; });
                });
            </script>

            <div id="photo">
                <img src="image source"/>
                <img src="image source"/>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You reeally need to indent that code better.

Comment: Unbelievable mess. Mass of events which conflict with each others. Why do you need to dynamically wrap the image if the only thing you do is zooming the image? Why do you use all that `return false;`? And why do you specify css rules for img if they are the same as default?

Comment: @Yuri i was trying to make the image that is non active from the pare to stay in it`s position. I use all that return false to make the code run only once per click per image because if you click a second time on the image that is zoomed in it makes a new div cret in the div cret that exist already. And the huge mess is because I`m a neube :D

Comment: This why in jQuery there is `event.stopPropagation()`. Actually you problem is not the javascript: such functionality could be written with dozen lines of code. Main problem is CSS as usual cause you will need position all corresponding elements in the way to eliminate default browser's animation glitches.

Comment: @Yuri i want to try to use a clone of the image, my goal is to make a image zoomer with jQuery because i did not find one that uses jquery and enlarges images on click i hoped to make one to be used like a shadowbox butt with a different effect. And maybe with iframe and other content butt my skils aren`t that great.

Comment: I mean, that script for that will be pretty simple. And I'm not against your solution and jQuery, but you should be careful with styles, cause in your case this will be the main headache.

Comment: I agree butt no one has answered my question :(

Comment: Come one everybody you all knowing programmers this is a simple question does anybody know how to answer

Answer (score 2):

To limit the scope of the selector, you can specify a more precise jquery selector
instead of $('img') $('#photo img'); it will affect only img present in photo id div.

you should review your selector and the animate will be more effectively use in correct one...
like put your animate only on img.selected.

Hope it helps http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ok @Kidi butt that is not a complete answer come one I think you can do more